# VSCode: Different terminal account

Tags: visual-studio-code

I am using VSCode in Linux Ubuntu for my coding purposes. And I use the the existing terminal in the VSCode, The Terminal in VSCode and the OS terminal share the same history of commands. Is there any way to have separate profile for VSCode so that the each of the terminals have its own history.